# Como abrir o Messenger Customer Chat Plugin do Facebook a partir de outro botão?

Tags: javascript, facebook, chat, facebook-javascript-sdk

Estou implementando o plugin de Chat do Facebook em um site, onde o mesmo renderiza um iframe na pagina. Gostaria de saber se é possivel utilizar um botão da minha página para fazer a mesma ação do botão que abre o chat no iframe...

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Eu tentei mover o iframe para dentro do link mas não tive sucesso pois o botão perde a funcionalidade, segue o código que eu implementei:

```
//pega o iframe
var getBtChat = $(".fb_dialog.fb_dialog_advanced");

//remove da pagina
$(".fb_dialog.fb_dialog_advanced").remove();

//coloca dentro do link
$("a#btFacebook").append(getBtChat);
```

Toda ajuda é bem vinda...

Comment: Deixa eu ver se entendi, a conversa não está sendo expandida?

Comment: @Jorge Ao clicar no botão do facebook abre a janela, eu gostaria de utilizar o meu botão para abrir a janela...o facebook renderiza o botão default solto na pagina

Comment: Fazendo a associação do evento `click` ao seu botão `$('#botao').click(function(){...})` e jogar colocar um `$('#seuFrame').show()` não resolve? Tem que saber como o botão próprio do face está fazendo essa chamada, ai só copiar.

Comment: Se a página estiver hospedada e puder passar o link, dou uma olhada, ou se possível, escreva o código [aqui](https://jsfiddle.net/) para fins de teste.

Comment: Cara, algum tempo atrás eu queria fazer algo parecido com isso. Então acabei encontrando uma solução que serve inclusive para WhatsApp e é mto simples de implementar. Pode ser que te ajude: https://lucianobragaweb.github.io/integrar-whatsapp-no-site